# how to copy nested if condition to all columns in MS excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've a excel in which sheet1 contains the following data
[image: Sheet1]

and sheet2 contains the following,
[image: Sheet2]

I wanted to update the Sheet1 2d column with the Cost rates between the slab defined in Sheet2, manually entered values in ColumnD as follows. But I need to do it using formula
[image: Exptected]

The formula that I've used is,

`=IF(
    AND(
       A2>=Sheet2!A2,
       A2<=Sheet2!B2
    ),Sheet2!C2,
  IF(
    AND(
       A2>=Sheet2!A3,
       A2<=Sheet2!B3
    ),Sheet2!C3,
  IF(
    AND(
       A2>=Sheet2!A4,
       A2<=Sheet2!B4
    ),Sheet2!C4,
  IF(
    AND(
       A2>=Sheet2!A5,
       A2<=Sheet2!B5
    ),Sheet2!C5,
  IF(
    AND(
       A2>=Sheet2!A6,
       A2<=Sheet2!B6
    ),Sheet2!C6
)))))` 
And it worked for first column, when i dragged it to all the columns I wanted to increment A2 to A3 and so on, but not sheet2 columns.
How can I do this?

Could someone please help on this?

Comment: Not sure this is what you meant but you can fix references you don't want to change with $ before either the column or row or both e.g. $AS1, $A1, A$1. Absolute cell references.

Comment: Hey thanks! that worked. Added $A$2 and so on, and this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix references you don't want to change with $ before either the column or row or both e.g. $A1, A$1, $A$1. This is called an [Absolute](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/) cell reference.

Or you could use the following formula:

In `B2` put the following and drag down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6)),"Nothing")
```

Comment: what if no match found case? is it possible to print nothing instead of #N/A?

Comment: try the edit i have put up. Note that match has no specified third argument so defaults to closest match.